# How to login with bs4

Tags: python-2.7, authentication, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to login to website with requests and then parse another url on the same session using bs4 but i am unable to do so.

**Following is the html for login page**

```
<pre class="string" id="auth_user_username" name="username" value="" type="text">
<b class="password" id="auth_user_password" name="password" value="" type="password">
<b class="checkbox" id="auth_user_remember" name="remember" value="on" type="checkbox">
<b value="Login" type="submit"></td><td class="w2p_fc">
<b="_next" value="/" type="hidden"><input name="_formkey" value="5f6182fa-1085-491a-8c3e-e69d11fc02f6" type="hidden"><input name="_formname" value="login" type="hidden">
```

**And this is the code snippet I'm trying**

```
import requests
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


res = requests.get(base_url)


# This is the form data that the page sends when logging in

login_data = {
    'username': 'user1',
    'password': '123456',
    'submit': 'id',
}

r = res.post(base_url, data=login_data)

page = urllib2.urlopen('https://test-link.aka.automate.com/perf/view?project=' + branchName + '&suites=Automation').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

Comment: Login form is like this input class="string" id="auth_user_username" name="username" value="" type="text"

input class="password" id="auth_user_password" name="password" value="" type="password"

input class="checkbox" id="auth_user_remember" name="remember" value="on" type="checkbox"

input value="Login" type="submit"></td><td class="w2p_fc"

input name="_next" value="/" type="hidden" input name="_formkey" value="5f6182fa-1085-491a-8c3e-e69d11fc02f6" type="hidden" input name="_formname" value="login" type="hidden"

Comment: Use `selenium` library and its `send_keys()` method along with bs4 for info read [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)